# Localization for ASP.NET Core 3.0 doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, localization

As the title says localization doesn't work, I get only key not the value here is all necessary code.

ConfigurationServices

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        services.AddMvc().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization().AddViewLocalization(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix, options =>
        options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("sr")
            };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

        });
    }
```

Configure

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseRequestLocalization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    public IStringLocalizer<Resource> _localizer;

    public HomeController(
        ILogger<HomeController> logger,
        IStringLocalizer<Resource> localizer)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HandleError]
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

Resource

```
namespace WebApplication.Resources
{
    public class Resource
    {
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using WebApplication.Resources

@inject IStringLocalizer<Resource> localizer
@inject IViewLocalizer _localizer

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
    <p>@localizer["Hello"]</p>
    <p>@_localizer["Hello"]</p>
</div>
```

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfinu.png)

In Resources folder I have class Resource and two .resx files (Resource.en.resx, Resource.sr.resx) they both contain one key Hello. In the view I'm trying to display value of that key with IStringLocalizer and with IViewLocalizer but without luck. Can someone tell me where is the problem, what am I doing wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be careful with the namespace of the class you are acquiring the `IStringLocalizer` for. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#resource-file-naming):

> Resources are named for the full type name of their class minus the assembly name.

The full type name of your `Resource` class is `WebApplication.Resources.Resource` and subtracting the assembly name you get `Resources.Resource`. Also you have specified "Resources" as the root path for your resource files (`services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources")`). This means when you acquire `IStringLocalizer<Resource>` it'll try to locate your resource file at `<project root>/Resources/Resources.Resource.en.resx` (for English localization).

You have a few options:

### 1. Modify namespace of your Resource class

In your `Resource.cs` use the following namespace:

```
namespace WebApplication
{ ... }
```

Now the localizer will look for the resource file at `<project root>/Resources/Resource.en.resx` (or `<project root>/Resources.Resource.en.resx` - dots or path separators don't matter)

### 2. Rename your RESX files

Since the localizer is currently looking for the file at `<project root>/Resources/Resources.Resource.en.resx` you could simply rename your `Resource.en.resx` to `Resources.Resource.en.resx`

### 3. Don't set relative ResourcesPath

In `Startup.cs` when you configure localization you can skip setting `ResourcesPath` so that the localizer will look for the file relative to the projects root folder:

```
// Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices()
services.AddLocalization();
```

Now the localizer will look for the file at the path `<project root>/Resources/Resource.en.resx`.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. You are a hero!

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to this scenario, in my case I was struggling a couple of hours with the very same situation.
By reading the answer, and opening the [DOCUMENTATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#resource-file-naming) (Above linked)

I realice that my nTier MVC project had Root-name-spaces such as:
a) PROJ-Models
b) PROJ-DAO
c) PROJ-Repo
...

This "-" leads to the whole Localization not working at all.
**Changing to "_"** (underscore) worked smoothly!

SOURCE:
RootNamespaceAttribute
The RootNamespaceAttribute attribute provides the root namespace of an assembly when the root namespace of an assembly is different than the assembly name.

Warning

This can occur when a project's name is not a valid .NET identifier. For instance my-project-name.csproj will use the root namespace my_project_name and the assembly name my-project-name leading to this error.